# How to return filter out array of objects which is not exist in array value in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to filter out array of objects where the Street_ID is not existing in the given array

Example:

```
[{UserID: “0GO63EQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX”, UserAge: “20”, Street_ID: “56478” }, { UserID: “REGOPQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX”, UserAge: “30”, Street_ID: “98474” }, { UserID: “524EREQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX”, UserAge: “80”, Street_ID: “25697” }]
```

With the array value `[25697,56478]`

My expected result should look like this:

```
[{ UserID: “REGOPQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX”, UserAge: “30”, Street_ID: “98474” }]
```

Since the Street_ID `98474` is not in this array `[25697,56478]`

This is what is try show far

```
        const streets = Response.filter(street => {
            for (let index = 0; index < userArray.length; index++) {
                const element = userArray[index];
                return street.Street_ID !== element;
            }
        });


console.log(streets);
```

but I get this as a return

```
[{UserID: “0GO63EQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX”, UserAge: “20”, Street_ID: “56478” }, { UserID: “REGOPQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX”, UserAge: “30”, Street_ID: “98474” }]
```

Thanks for your HELP!!!

Comment: `data.filter(({Street_ID})=>!userArray.includes(Street_ID)` but make sure userArray is has strings instead of numbers.

Comment: @HRM that solution is not clear enough

Comment: @HRM It work thanks so much you save my headache since yesterday :) kindly drop it as an answer so I can Up Vote it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const data = [
  {
    UserID: '0GO63EQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX',
    UserAge: '20',
    Street_ID: '56478',
  },
  {
    UserID: 'REGOPQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX',
    UserAge: '30',
    Street_ID: '98474',
  },
  {
    UserID: '524EREQTFEZ7HO6FBDPX',
    UserAge: '80',
    Street_ID: '25697',
  },
];
//I changed the ids to strings
const userArray = ['25697', '56478'];
console.log(
  'filtered result:',
  data.filter(
    ({ Street_ID }) => !userArray.includes(Street_ID)
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks man, I already add your identity to my source code

Answer (score 0):

@HRM got it right within few seconds

```
data.filter(({Street_ID})=>!userArray.includes(Street_ID)
```